# Extraction of data from pdf

Tags: python, sql, pdf, data-extraction

I am developing a project as part of an internship for a research institute.
For that I have to feed my SQL database, with data from pdf files, like the one below:

https://www.mairie-orly.fr/content/download/11449/88884/file/Menu+du+mois+de+janvier+2021.pdf

I currently convert my pdf files to JSON via the pdftotext API, this is the best JSON output I have found so far. Here is the result:

```json
{
  "document": {
    "page": {
      "@index": "0",
      "row": [
        {
          "column": [
            {
              "text": ""
            },
            {
              "text": ""
            },
            {
              "text": {
                "@fontName": "Arial",
                "@fontSize": "10.0",
                "@fontStyle": "Bold",
                "@x": "271.10",
                "@y": "101.78",
                "@width": "29.40",
                "@height": "9.72",
                "#text": "LUNDI"
              }
            },
            {
              "text": {
                "@fontName": "Arial",
                "@fontSize": "10.0",
                "@fontStyle": "Bold",
                "@x": "476.09",
                "@y": "101.78",
                "@width": "31.26",
                "@height": "9.72",
                "#text": "MARDI"
              }

etc....etc...etc...
```

I need to feed my database with a menu and a corresponding date.

Maybe my conversion is not adapted to the problem?
How can I retrieve a menu and the corresponding date? Which path should I follow?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract the data from the pdf you can try to make a request using urllib and retrive the text using tika apache. With urllib you can choose to save the file local and get the text from the file like this

```
import urllib.request
from tika import parser

url = 'https://www.mairie-orly.fr/content/download/11449/88884/file/Menu+du+mois+de+janvier+2021.pdf'

urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, './a.pdf')

file_data = parser.from_file('./a.pdf')

text = file_data['content']

#print for debug
print(text)
```

For tika you need to install java (Latest version) and pip install tika

hope it helps! enois

Comment: Thanks, but the simple text is not usable in my case. I've opened a trail with Camelot-py, and maybe this is the right way. In any case a very powerful PDF to Excel